# How to select the 2nd column after the pattern found, patterns is '100'

Tags: linux, shell, awk, grep

`cat file_1`:

```
height 100  3 name
gray   125  8 yellow
base   100  5 age
red    455  9 tea
level  100  7 yak
```

my final final file should have only 2nd columns which contain pattern '100'

`cat final_file`:

```
name 
age
yak
```

Comment: Is this something you want `awk '$2 ~ 100 {print $NF}'` ?  Posting as a comment since I'm not sure if I understand your question.

Comment: @val0x00ff based on title, that is what OP seems to want and works for given input, not so sure if OP wants to search for pattern only from second column

Comment: @Sundeep I still don't understand what second column is in this case. `age, tea, yak` is the last column so that's why.

Comment: @val0x00ff, 2nd column after match.. my understanding is that say OP wanted to match `base`, then get `5`

Comment: Why does the sample output have only one column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As val0x00ff suggests, `awk` can cover this

This would match 100 anywhere in field 2, e.g. "foo100bar" would match.

```
awk '$2 ~ 100 {print $NF}' file_1 >final_file
```

This would only match 100 being in field 2.

```
awk '$2 == "100" { print $NF }' file_1 >final_file
```

Answer (score 1):

In a general case I would do something like following code:

```
#!/bin/bash
matching_column=2  
filename="def"
awk -v matching_col=${matching_column}\
    -v printing_col=$((matching_column+2))\
    '$matching_col ~ 100 {printf "%s\n", $printing_col}' "$filename"
```

In this manner you can select the column that must match the `pattern` using the variable `matching_col`. Then, the column to be printet is calculated as `printing_col=matching_column+2`. And than you can print the value specified in the printing_column field using `$printing_col`.

Answer (score 0):

With `grep` and `pcre`, assumes white-space as column delimiters

```
$ cat ip.txt 
height 100  3 name
gray   125  8 yellow
base   100  5 age
red    455  9 tea
level  100  7 yak
```

Matching `100` in any column and extract text from 2nd column after that

```
$ grep -oP '\b100\s+\S+\s+\K\S+' ip.txt 
name
age
yak
```

Matching `100` in 2nd column and then getting text 2nd column after that

```
$ grep -oP '^\S+\s+100\s+\S+\s+\K\S+' ip.txt 
name
age
yak
```

Both make use of positive lookbehind - marked by `\K`. The first one uses `\b` to mark word boundary (to avoid matches like `1100`)

Add `> final_file` to command for saving the output

Answer (score 0):

I think steves awk solution above is the best, but since we're at it, here's a variant with sed

```
sed -n 's/.* 100 .* \([a-z].*$\)/\1/p' original_file > newfile
```

Which gets you...

```
cat newfile 
name
age
yak
```